# Django - Circular import with multiple files

Tags: python, django, model, circular-dependency

I have 3 python files within a package, I'm trying to import a class from one file into other 2 file. But i get error.

```
models
   __init__.py
   a.py
   b.py
   c.py
```

a.py

```
class ATestOne()
    pass

class ATestTwo()
    pass

class ATestThree()
    pass
```

b.py

```
from app.models.a import ATestOne, ATestTwo
from app.models.c import CTestOne

class BTestOne()
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(ATestOne)

class BTestTwo()
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(CTestOne)
```

c.py

```
from app.models.a import ATestOne, ATestThree
from app.models.b import BTestOne
class CTestOne()
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(ATestOne)

 class CTestTwo()
        field1 = models.ForeignKey(BTestOne)
```

Returns below mentioned error
ImportError: cannot import name 'ATestOne'

Kindly advice in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The circular import is clear between files `b.py` and `c.py`. Move the imports under the respective classes. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid circular import problems by referencing those models using strings, e.g.

```
class BTestOne()
    field1 = models.ForeignKey('app.ATestOne')

class BTestTwo()
    field1 = models.ForeignKey('app.CTestOne')
```

(If I guessed correctly, that `app` is the name of your application in which your models reside)

Comment: I tried this also I got error The field app.TrnPlag.tq_question was declared with a lazy reference to 'api.tqtrnquestions', but app 'app' doesn't provide model 'tqtrnquestions'.

Comment: What's the actual name of your app? How is it defined in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings? How did you declare it exactly in the `ForeignKey` definition?

Comment: Field defines a relation with model 'app.TqTrnQuestions', which is either not installed, or is abstract. The field app.TrnPlag.tq_question was declared with a lazy reference to 'app.tqtrnquestions', but app 'app' doesn't provide model 'tqtrnquestions'.

Comment: Tbh I'm lost, please update your original question with all relevant info and actual names, since you are posting errors with real names. Also, is `tqtrnquestions` a model? Why is in in lowercaps? - it's really confusing.